# unbeatable Tic Tac Toe

Tags: c++, algorithm

i'm trying to make a unbeatable tic tac toe for a side project and i can't make it right (i can actually beat it ironically).
It's actually a implementation of the MiniMax algorithm; i came with this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
struct Move
{
    int line, columns;
};
//Return the number of remainings turn based on the number of lest boxes
int remainingsTurns(char grid[3][3])
{
    int remainingTurn = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (grid[k][i] == ' ')
            {
                remainingTurn++;
            }
        }
    }
    return remainingTurn;
}
//Print the grid on screen
void printGrid(char grid[3][3])
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            cout << "| " << grid[k][i] << " ";
        }

        cout << "|" << endl;
    }

}
//Give a value to the board
int evaluateBoard(char grid[3][3])
{
    //Check the board for lines
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
        if (grid[k][0] == grid[k][1] && grid[k][1] == grid[k][2])
        {
            if (grid[k][0] == 'x')
            {
                return +10;
            }
            else if (grid[k][0] == 'o')
            {
                return -10;
            }
        }
    }

    //Check the board for columns
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
        if (grid[0][k] == grid[1][k] && grid[1][k] == grid[2][k])
        {
            if (grid[0][k] == 'x')
            {
                return +10;
            }
            else if (grid[0][k] == 'o')
            {
                return -10;
            }
        }
    }

    //Check the board for diagonals
    if (grid[0][0] == grid[1][1] && grid[0][0] == grid[2][2])
    {
        if (grid[0][0] == 'x')
        {
            return +10;
        }
        else if (grid[0][0] == 'o')
        {
            return -10;
        }
    }
    if (grid[0][2] == grid[1][1] && grid[0][2] == grid[2][0])
    {
        if (grid[0][0] == 'x')
        {
            return +10;
        }
        else if (grid[0][0] == 'o')
        {
            return -10;
        }
    }
    //if no ictory return 0
    return 0;
}
// MiniMax algorithm
int miniMax(char grid[3][3], int turn, bool maxMove)
{
    int score = evaluateBoard(grid);
    
    if (score == 10)
    {
        return score;
    }
    if (score == -10)
    {
        return score;
    }
    //Check if the game is a tie
    if (remainingsTurns(grid) == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (maxMove)
    {
        int best = -1000;
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (grid[k][i] == ' ')
                {
                    grid[k][i] = 'x';
                    best = max(best, miniMax(grid, turn + 1, !maxMove));
                    grid[k][i] = ' ';

                }
            }
        }
        return best;
    }
    else
    {
        int best = 1000;
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (grid[k][i] == ' ')
                {
                    grid[k][i] = 'o';
                    best = min(best, miniMax(grid, turn + 1, !maxMove));
                    grid[k][i] = ' ';
                }
            }
        }
        return best;
    }
}

Move playerMov(char grid[3][3])
{
    Move playerMove;
    int input = -1;
    cout << "Enter the column you want to play (1, 2 or 3)" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == 1 || input == 2 || input == 3)
    {
        playerMove.columns = input-1;
        input = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error, enter a valid number!" << endl;
        playerMov(grid);

    }
    cout << "Enter the line you want to play (1, 2 or 3)" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == 1 || input == 2 || input == 3)
    {
        playerMove.line = input-1;
        input = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error, enter a valid number!" << endl;
        playerMov(grid);

    }
    return playerMove;

}
//return the best move using the MiniMax
Move findMove(char grid[3][3])
{
    int best = -1000;
   
    Move move;
    move.line = -1;
    move.columns = -1;
    //Check all move to find if this move is the best possible move
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (grid[k][i] == ' ')
            {
                grid[k][i] = 'x';
                int moveValue = miniMax(grid, 0, false);
                grid[k][i] = ' ';
                if (moveValue > best)
                {
                    move.line = k;
                    move.columns = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return move;
}
int main()
{
    char grid[3][3];
    int turn = 0;
    Move playerMove, algoMove;
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            grid[k][i] = ' ';
        }
    }

    cout << "Welcome to the unbeatable Tic Tac Toe !" << endl;
    do
    {
        printGrid(grid);
        playerMove = playerMov(grid);
        grid[playerMove.line][playerMove.columns] = 'o';
        Move computerMove = findMove(grid);
        grid[computerMove.line][computerMove.columns] = 'x';

    } while (remainingsTurns(grid) > 0);

    cout << endl;
}
```

but the movements of the algorithm doesn't seems right, it always choose the bottom right corner and i don't understand why...
This implementation is largely inspired by [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimax-algorithm-in-game-theory-set-3-tic-tac-toe-ai-finding-optimal-move/) article from Geek for Geek where i tried to steal the algorithm but i can't get it right to make it fit for single player.
What do i miss?

Comment: Why are you checking `grid[0][0]` in the `grid[0][2] == grid[1][1] && grid[0][2] == grid[2][0]` case?

Comment: Also `playerMov(grid);` in the `playerMov` function should be `return playerMov(grid);`

Comment: because it's a bad test on my side --". Thank's for spotting it

Comment: Unrelated: To make it more C++ (instead of C) you could create your own `Board` class and put the free functions as member functions in that class. `class Board { char grid[3][3]; public: int evaluate(); };` and so on.

Comment: no, ```playerMov(grid)``` call the function again to make the user restart his input in case of a out of grid input (if the player try to enter another number instead of 1, 2 or 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple bugs in your code:

- You are checking the value of `grid[0][0]` in `grid[0][2] == grid[1][1] && grid[0][2] == grid[2][0]` case of the function `evaluateBoard`. It should be `grid[0][2]`.
- `playerMov(grid);` in the function `playerMov` should be `return playerMov(grid);`. Otherwise, the re-entered "correct" values will be dropped and (partly) uninitalized `playerMov` will be returned.
- You should update `best` to `moveValue` when `moveValue > best` in the function `findMove`. (this should be the cause of the issue on your question)